# Xamarin monotouch can't run simulator in debug mode

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

A very wired thing has happen, 
After updating to the latest Xamarin, I can't run my project on simulator in Debug mode. Xamarin will simply not let my choose as the destination for debug. (see in screen shot attached).

[image]

Also added a screen shot from Release mode where you can see I have an option to choose a simulator. I worked with Xamarin for more than a year. Never had something like that.

[image]

Comment: I only see one screenshot. Have you tried the ubiquitous "close and restart" everything (XS and OSX)? Is it just this project or *any* project that open? Worst case scenario, you could switch channels, install and restart, then switch back and repeat.

Comment: It looks like your project only has a `iPhone` and no `iPhoneSimulator` configuration (and both exists for Release builds).

Comment: How do I configure a iphoneSimulator for the debug mode?

Comment: I've the same problem, except that I've never used Xamarin before and this is all I get. I've just copied the instructions from a tutorial and have no option to run the program I'm creating. Destination is always disabled.